# Vuforia - Dynamic Object Recognition with a single ObjectTarget instance

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

1. Is it possible to track every object on a Data Set with a single ObjectTarget instance ? How ?
2. If not, is it possible to dynamicly create a ObjectTarget instance for every object within a DataSet, and attach a custom ObjectTargetBehaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer your 2nd question. **NO** Vuforia does not have the feature to dynamically load an object tracker. Their limitations lie within dynamically loading `Image Targets` only. But you can use the Object Scanner by Vuforia to scan your object and preload it into the application before deploying.

As for your first question, I'm unsure of what you're asking, but from what I understand, you cannot simply use the same `DataSet` for multiple objects (**?**) Each DataSet is a .dat or .xml of the features of one particular Image/Object. Hence, if the objects are the same. (Eg: Pepsi Can) then you can use the same `DataSet`, because the features and markings on the Pepsi can will be the same (*mostly). Hence if you need multiple objects working on your object, you can preload them separately and deploy them.

Hope that helps.